# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0 Android musicplayer

Tags: java, android

I'm developing a music application but i keep geting this error, i don't understand it and dont know how to solve. I'm stuck for 2 day trying to re-write the code but still the error pops-up.My logcat comes up as java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0. And please elaborate the main problem.

This MainActivity.java

```
  package com.developer.bunamay.player;

      import android.app.SearchManager;
      import android.content.ComponentName;
      import android.content.Context;
      import android.content.Intent;
      import android.content.ServiceConnection;
      import android.content.res.Resources;
      import android.graphics.Bitmap;
      import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
      import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
      import android.os.Bundle;
      import android.os.Handler;
      import android.os.IBinder;
      import android.os.Message;
      import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
      import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
      import android.text.TextUtils;
      import android.util.Log;
      import android.view.Menu;
      import android.view.MenuItem;
      import android.view.View;
      import android.view.animation.Animation;
      import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
      import android.widget.AdapterView;
      import android.widget.Button;
      import android.widget.ImageView;
      import android.widget.LinearLayout;
      import android.widget.ListView;
      import android.widget.SearchView;
      import android.widget.SeekBar;
      import android.widget.TextView;

      import java.util.List;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MusicService.MediaFileListener {

public static final PlayerUtils PlayerController = PlayerUtils.getInstance();

public static final int PICK_FOLDER_REQUEST = 8;
private MediaFileAdapter mediaFileAdapter = null;
private TextView playingSong;
private Button btnPause, btnPlay, btnNext, btnPrevious;
private Button btnStop;
private LinearLayout linearLayoutPlayingSong;
private ListView mediaListView;
private SeekBar seekbar;
private TextView textBufferDuration, textDuration;
private ImageView imageViewAlbumArt;
private Context context;

MusicService mService;
boolean mBound = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    context = MainActivity.this;
    init();

    if (!PlayerUtils.isServiceRunning(MusicService.class.getName(), getApplicationContext())) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MusicService.class);
        startService(i);
    }
}

private void init() {
    initViews();
    setListeners();
    playingSong.setSelected(true);
    seekbar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorText), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    if (PlayerController.SONGS_LIST.size() <= 0) {
        PlayerController.SONGS_LIST = PlayerController.listOfSongs(getApplicationContext());
    }
    initAdapter();
}

private void initAdapter() {
    mediaFileAdapter = new MediaFileAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_list, PlayerController.SONGS_LIST);
    mediaListView.setAdapter(mediaFileAdapter);
    mediaListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    mediaListView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
}

private void initViews() {
    playingSong = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textNowPlaying);
    mediaListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewMusic);
    btnPause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPause);
    btnPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
    linearLayoutPlayingSong = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutPlayingSong);
    seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    btnStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
    textBufferDuration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textBufferDuration);
    textDuration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textDuration);
    imageViewAlbumArt = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewAlbumArt);
    btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
    btnPrevious = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPrevious);
}

private Animation setButtonAnimation() {
    return AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.button_anim);
}

// defines callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService()
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                                   IBinder service) {
        MusicService.LocalBinder binder = (MusicService.LocalBinder) service;
        mService = binder.getService();
        mService.setListener(MainActivity.this);
        mBound = true;

    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        mBound = false;
        mService = null;

    }
};


private void setListeners() {
    mediaListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View item, int position, long id) {
            PlayerController.SONG_PAUSED = false;
            PlayerController.SONG_NUMBER = position;
            boolean isServiceRunning = PlayerUtils.isServiceRunning(MusicService.class.getName(), getApplicationContext());
            if (!isServiceRunning) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MusicService.class);
                startService(i);
            } else {
                PlayerController.SONG_CHANGE_HANDLER.sendMessage(
                        PlayerController.SONG_CHANGE_HANDLER.obtainMessage());
            }
            updateUI();
            changeButton();
        }
    });

    btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PlayerController.playControl(getApplicationContext());
        }
    });
    btnPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PlayerController.pauseControl(getApplicationContext());
        }
    });
    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            v.startAnimation(setButtonAnimation());
            PlayerController.nextControl(getApplicationContext());
        }
    });
    btnPrevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            v.startAnimation(setButtonAnimation());
            PlayerController.previousControl(getApplicationContext());
        }
    });
    btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (PlayerUtils.isServiceRunning(MusicService.class.getName(), getApplicationContext())) {
                PlayerController.pauseControl(getApplicationContext());
            }
            linearLayoutPlayingSong.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

    seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            if (fromUser) {
                // clicked position on the seekBar
                int currentSeekBarPosition = seekBar.getProgress();
                // 1% of song duration = song duration / 100%
                int onePercentOfSongDuration = (mService.getDuration() / 100);
                // associate song duration with clicked position on the seekBar
                int changedPosition = currentSeekBarPosition * onePercentOfSongDuration;

                // seek to selected position
                PlayerController.seekToAnyControl(getApplicationContext(), changedPosition);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if (mBound) {
        unbindService(mConnection);
    }
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MusicService.class);
    bindService(i, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    handleAudioFromOpenWithPopup();

    boolean isServiceRunning = PlayerUtils.isServiceRunning(MusicService.class.getName(), getApplicationContext());
    if (isServiceRunning) {
        updateUI();
    } else {
        linearLayoutPlayingSong.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    changeButton();
    PlayerController.SEEKBAR_HANDLER = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            Integer i[] = (Integer[]) msg.obj;
            textBufferDuration.setText(PlayerUtils.getDuration(i[0]));
            textDuration.setText(PlayerUtils.getDuration(i[1]));
            seekbar.setProgress(i[2]);
        }
    };
}

public void updateUI() {
    MediaFile mediaFile = PlayerController.SONGS_LIST.get(PlayerController.SONG_NUMBER);
    String nowPlayingTitleText = mediaFile.getTitle() + " " + mediaFile.getArtist() + "-" + mediaFile.getAlbum();
    playingSong.setText(nowPlayingTitleText);
    Bitmap albumArt = PlayerController.getAlbumart(context, mediaFile.getAlbumId());
    if (albumArt != null) {
        imageViewAlbumArt.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(Resources.getSystem(), albumArt));
    } else {
        Bitmap defaultAlbumArt = PlayerController.getDefaultAlbumArt(context);
        imageViewAlbumArt.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(Resources.getSystem(), defaultAlbumArt));
    }
    linearLayoutPlayingSong.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

public void changeButton() {
    if (PlayerController.SONG_PAUSED) {
        btnPause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        btnPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btnPlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

public void changeUI() {
    updateUI();
    changeButton();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

    // init menu items for search
    MenuItem itemSearchTitle = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search_title);
    MenuItem itemSearchAlbum = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search_album);
    MenuItem itemSearchArtist = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search_artist);

    SearchView searchViewTitle = (SearchView) itemSearchTitle.getActionView();
    SearchView searchViewAlbum = (SearchView) itemSearchAlbum.getActionView();
    SearchView searchViewArtist = (SearchView) itemSearchArtist.getActionView();

    searchViewTitle.setFocusable(true);
    searchViewAlbum.setFocusable(true);
    searchViewArtist.setFocusable(true);

    // init searchable info for each menu item
    searchViewTitle.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchViewTitle.setQueryHint("title...");
    searchViewTitle.setIconified(true);

    searchViewAlbum.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchViewAlbum.setQueryHint("album...");
    searchViewAlbum.setIconified(true);

    searchViewArtist.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchViewArtist.setQueryHint("artist...");
    searchViewArtist.setIconified(true);

    // set textChangeListeners for each type of search
    final SearchView.OnQueryTextListener textChangeListenerTitle = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
                mediaFileAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return true;
        }
    };

    SearchView.OnQueryTextListener textChangeListenerAlbum = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
                mediaFileAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return true;
        }
    };

    SearchView.OnQueryTextListener textChangeListenerArtist = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
                mediaFileAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return true;
        }
    };

    // apply listeners to searchViews
    searchViewTitle.setOnQueryTextListener(textChangeListenerTitle);
    searchViewAlbum.setOnQueryTextListener(textChangeListenerAlbum);
    searchViewArtist.setOnQueryTextListener(textChangeListenerArtist);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    // get music from specific folder
    if (id == R.id.folder_music) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, FolderPickerActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FOLDER_REQUEST);
        return true;
    }
    // fetch all music from device
    if (id == R.id.all_music) {
        PlayerController.SONGS_LIST = PlayerController.listOfSongs(getApplicationContext());
        initAdapter();

        return true;
    }

    // search songs by title
    if (id == R.id.action_search_title) {
        PlayerController.SEARCH_TYPE = "TITLE";

        return true;
    }
    // search songs by artist
    if (id == R.id.action_search_artist) {
        PlayerController.SEARCH_TYPE = "ARTIST";

        return true;
    }
    // search songs by album
    if (id == R.id.action_search_album) {
        PlayerController.SEARCH_TYPE = "ALBUM";

        return true;
    }

    if (id == R.id.action_sort_title) {
        MediaFileComparator.sortByTitle(PlayerController.SONGS_LIST);
        MediaFileAdapter mediaAdapter = (MediaFileAdapter) mediaListView.getAdapter();
        mediaAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.action_sort_album) {
        MediaFileComparator.sortByAlbum(PlayerController.SONGS_LIST);
        MediaFileAdapter mediaAdapter = (MediaFileAdapter) mediaListView.getAdapter();
        mediaAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.action_sort_artist) {
        MediaFileComparator.sortByArtist(PlayerController.SONGS_LIST);
        MediaFileAdapter mediaAdapter = (MediaFileAdapter) mediaListView.getAdapter();
        mediaAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.action_sort_duration) {
        MediaFileComparator.sortByDuration(PlayerController.SONGS_LIST);
        MediaFileAdapter mediaAdapter = (MediaFileAdapter) mediaListView.getAdapter();
        mediaAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        if (requestCode == PICK_FOLDER_REQUEST) {

            String pickedFolder = data.getStringExtra("pickedFolder");
            Log.i("PICKER_FOLDER_TAG", pickedFolder);

            // get last subfolder from path as WHERE arg
            pickedFolder = getSelectionArg(pickedFolder);
            Log.i("PICKER_FOLDER_WHERE_TAG", pickedFolder);

            // reinit music list and adapter with data from specific folder
            List<MediaFile> songsFromSpecificFolder = PlayerController.getSongsFromSpecificFolder(
                    getApplicationContext(), new String[]{pickedFolder}
            );
            if (songsFromSpecificFolder.size() != 0) {
                PlayerController.SONGS_LIST = songsFromSpecificFolder;
                PlayerController.SONG_NUMBER = 0;
                initAdapter();
            }
        }
    }
}

// receive audio action from 'Complete action with' pop-up
private void handleAudioFromOpenWithPopup() {
    // receive Intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    // check action
    String action = intent.getAction();
    // if it's audio action view
    if (action != null && action.equals("android.intent.action.VIEW")) {
        // play song
        PlayerController.playMusicFromActionPicker(this, intent.getData());
    }
}

// get last subfolder from path as WHERE arg
private String getSelectionArg(String path) {
    String sTag = "%";
    // substring last directory in path
    String lastSubfolder = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    return sTag + lastSubfolder + sTag;
}

@Override
public void onMediaFileChanged() {
    changeUI();
}

@Override
public void onPlayPauseActionChanged() {
    changeButton();
}
```

}

I've tried searching online varios times but i still dont understand. 
Thanks

Comment: What line is causing the error?

Comment: on updateUI you should check PlayerController.SONGS_LIST.size() > 0

Comment: Where is your stacktrace?

Comment: On UpdateUI @TychoTheTaco

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of the problem is that somewhere, either your code or some code that your code uses is doing something that is equivalent to this:

```
Object[] array = new Object[0];
...
System.out.println(array[0]);
```

Something created an array (of some type) with size ZERO, and it (or maybe something else) is trying to access the first element (index zero) of that array.  That is beyond the end of the array ... and that results in an exception.

---

I can't see where you are creating a zero-length array in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Could you have a look at the method `protected void onResume()`?

I think, you may have a problem in following lines:

```
Integer i[] = (Integer[]) msg.obj;
textBufferDuration.setText(PlayerUtils.getDuration(i[0]));
textDuration.setText(PlayerUtils.getDuration(i[1]));
seekbar.setProgress(i[2]);
```

First try running the program by commenting out those lines. It may happen that, on some occasions, your `msg.obj` is actually an array whose length is 0. Then you will get `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0`. Hope it helps you.